# React state for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have arrays ( 5 - 8 ) like shown below, how can I use react seState the select the number of question (objects) to be returned for each individual array.

```js
const topic = [{
    questions: "The one question is here",
    answer: "A",
    answers: {
      a: "this is option A",
      b: "this is option B",
      c: "this is option C",
      d: "this is option D",
    }
  },
  {
    questions: "The two question is here",
    answer: "A",
    answers: {
      a: "this is option A",
      b: "this is option B",
      c: "this is option C",
      d: "this is option D",
    }
  }
]
```

)to actually select the number of objects to be returned by each array

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want but according to what I understand you can assign an `Id` to each question you can use `uuid` for example like this :

```js
const topic = [{
    id:1,
    questions: "The one question is here",
    answer: "A",
    answers: {
      a: "this is option A",
      b: "this is option B",
      c: "this is option C",
      d: "this is option D",
    }
  },
  {
    id:2,
    questions: "The two question is here",
    answer: "A",
    answers: {
      a: "this is option A",
      b: "this is option B",
      c: "this is option C",
      d: "this is option D",
    }
  }
]
```

now you have id for each question you can set in state something like this

```
state={
  {id:1,count:2},
  {id:2,count:3}
}
```

now you have id of each questions and count of returned each item . now you can do what you want .